# Cannot close unresponsive Minimize Unmaximize... dialog

Tags: unity, dialog

The dialog is open and always on top of every window, as in the top right corner of the screenshot [image: screenshot] The dialog does not respond to clicking - any click either does nothing or triggers a button behind the dialog, e.g. Back for the browser. How to get rid of this dialog without restarting the computer?

The problem started by pressing Alt+N or some nearby key combination (finger slipped) in PyCharm. It has occurred before in other programs with some accidental key combination press that I do not remember.

Restarting eliminates the dialog.

Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Latitude E7470.